# Как в minishop2 вывести варианты видов доставки в карточку товара?

Tags: modx, minishop2

Куплен компонент https://modstore.pro/packages/delivery/mscdek.
Но в карточке товара вывод доставки только для одного вида доставки (в настройках компонента). А как вывести все активные доставки в карточке товара?
Да если и без этого компонента - как вывести те же Самовывоз и Курьер?

Comment: Все активные виды доставки выводятся на странице оформления заказа, но там стоимость для каждого вида тоже выводится не сразу, а прокликиванием по кнопкам)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути, получить все доставки которые активны в настройках можно следующим образом:

1) В сниппетах

```
$query = $modx->newQuery('msDelivery');
$query->where(array(
    'id:>' => 0,
    'active' => 1
));
$deliveries = $modx->getCollection('msDelivery', $query);

foreach($deliveries as $delivery){
    ......
    Здесь обрабатываете как вам угодно
    ......
}
```

2) В шаблоне\чанке их можно получить следующим образом:

```
{'!pdoResources' | snippet : [
    'class' => 'msDelivery',
    'sortby' => 'id',
    'where' => 'active = 1'
]}
```

Если не указывать tpl - то можно будет увидеть все доступные поля. А именно (доступны что в чанках, что в сниппетах, различия только в способе их получения):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Доставка курьером
    [description] => 
    [price] => 500
    [weight_price] => 0
    [distance_price] => 0
    [logo] => 
    [rank] => 1
    [active] => 1
    [class] => 
    [properties] => 
    [requires] => 
)
```

Comment: Ок, примерно так и думал, что только через новый сниппет. Вторая половина вопроса - как тут же на странице получить стоимость для каждого вида доставки?

Comment: Имеется ввиду - как получить стоимость с запросом на СДЭК?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, в сниппете:

```
//Получаем активные доставки
$res='';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM modx_ms2_deliveries WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY rank";
foreach ($modx->query($sql) as $row) {
    $res .= $row['description'];
}
```

Все-таки getCollection как-то пугает, чо он там собирает в коллекцию, одному богу известно))) А у меня все по плану и все можно отрегулировать.